# Inner Product of two polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Show that the function $<p(x), q(x)>$ = $p(−1)q(−1) + p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1)$ defines an inner product on $P_2(R)$

I know that an inner product has to hold three conditions, but I am not exactly sure if I use $<1 + x + x^2, 1 +x + x^2>$.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This symbol $\langle p,q\rangle$ is defined above. Nothing prevents you to substitute $p=q=1+x+x^2$. (For this, you will have to substitute $x=-1,0$ and $1$ into this polynomial.) What is your question, more specifically?

Comment: I believe our prof wants to prove

i)  $x, y, z$ is an element of $R^n$ and $c$ is an element of $R$, $<cx + y, z> = c<x, z> + <y, z>$
ii)$<x, y> = <y, x>
iii) $<x,x>$ > $0$, $x=0$, $<x, x>=0

Comment: I imagine you are supposed to prove that this is a valid inner product for any generic polynomials of order 2, $p(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ and $q(x) = b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0$. Try to show that this satisfies all the properties of an inner product.

Comment: @Stack: Yes, exactly, but now $x,y,z$ play the role of the polynomials (of degree $\le 2$ -- which you omitted from the question), probably better to rename these variables e.g. $p,q,r$.

Comment: Does $p(-1)q(-1) + p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1)$ = 14 = $<p(x), q(x)>$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)  satisfies three properties: conjugate symmetry, linearity, and positive-definiteness. You need to show that these properties are satisfied for every pair of elements from the vector space of polynomials of degree 2.

That is, you need to show that 
$$\langle p(x),q(x) \rangle = p(−1)q(−1) + p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1)$$
 satisfies the above properties for any two polynomials $p(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ and $q(x) = b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0$.

Here is a proof for the symmetry property:

$$\langle p(x),q(x) \rangle = p(−1)q(−1) + p(0)q(0) + p(1)q(1) = q(−1)p(−1) + q(0)p(0) + q(1)p(1) = \langle q(x),p(x) \rangle$$

Can you try proving the other two properties? You will need to find explicit values for $p(-1)$, $p(0)$, $p(1)$, etc.

For example: $$p(-1) = a_2(-1)^2 + a_1(-1) + a_0 = a_2 - a_1 + a_0$$

Comment: If $r(x)=c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2$, then $<p(x) + q(x), r(x)>$ $=$ $<p(x), z(x)> + <q(x) + r(x)>$  = $p(−1)z(−1) + p(0)z(0) + p(1)z(1) + q(−1)z(−1) +q(0)z(0)+ q(1)z(1)$ = $<p(x) + q(x), r(x)>$? That can't be right though, I am not sure when$$p(-1) = a_2(-1)^2 + a_1(-1) + a_0 = a_2 - a_1 + a_0$$ comes into use.

Comment: @Stack I would explicitly show that you can factor the $z$ terms out of the expression in your comment. After that, it should be obvious that the operation is linear. And plugging in values for $x$ is required to show positive-definiteness.